# Rails - Visiting URLs in a rake task - Sockets Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm attempting to create a rake tasks that visits a series of URLs, logs the status code, and then prints them to console. My code is as follows:

```
require 'csv'
require 'net/http'
require "open-uri"

namespace :routes do
  desc "check status codes"
  task check_301s: :environment do
    # open_csv
    # edit_urls
    generate_routes
    # visit_urls
    # log_status_codes
    visit_and_log_routes
    # give_results
  end

  def generate_routes
    csv = CSV.open('lib/better.csv', headers: true)
    @urls = []
    csv.each do |row|
      @urls << row['url'].gsub('foo', 'localhost:3000')
    end
  end

  def visit_and_log_routes
    responses = []
    @urls.each do |url|
      http = Net::HTTP.new(url, 3000)
      response = http.request_get('/')
      responses << response
    end
    puts responses
  end
end
```

I'm receiving the following error code when running this from terminal:

```
SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3000/children-centre/london/greenwich/eltham-childrens-centre/join:3000 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

I'm not sure if there is an easier way to visit URLs and log their status code, if so please let me know how to do it, and if not then how I can correct this error message. I'm assuming I'm simply leaving out the relevant options but am not sure how / where to add them.

Comment: Looks like you're concatenating an extra :3000 at the end of your url, not sure if that's preventing the visit. Perhaps try eliminating the second parameter in the call to `NET::HTTP.new`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I think I have to put the 3000 to assign the port as I'm testing local sites - without this the terminal tries to access outside sites via port 80.

Comment: Ah, I thought the `gsub('foo', 'localhost:3000')` was handling that.

Comment: `@urls.each` happens after the `.gsub` so you are re-appending the 3000

Comment: In case anyone makes the same error I did... adding http:// before localhost:3000 fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone making the same impressive error I was... the route needs http:// at the start instead of just localhost:3000